# Windows rsync, why all files copied over c drive when i copy from d to f

Tags: windows, debian, rsync

So this is a bit questionable and confusing.

I am using Debian subsystem on Windows. And through that i copy and backup files with rsync but i am running into problem where for some reason every file on backup goes through C drive.

Problem is my C drive don't have enough space so with large file i run out of space. Which is quite confusing because i copy files from D to F drive, with both drives having enough space. Question is why rsync is copying every file from D to C drive than sync it on F drive?

Here is command i use.

```
rsync -av --delete /mnt/d/Backup/ /mnt/f/Backup/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer, although the drive letters remained same in my pc, it looks like debian changed drive letters in it. It might be that some usb stick was pluged in when i connected my HDD's so after looking at drives i found correct mountpoint.